# Initializing static global data using function call (at compile time)

Tags: c++, performance, static

I am trying to save compute time by computing sequences of numbers at compile time and storing them as static vectors (but I might settle for computation once at the beginning of runtime for now).  A simple (not compiling) example of what I am trying to do would be:

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

static vector<vector<int> > STATIC_THING(4, vector<int>(4));

void Generator(int x, int y, vector<int> *output) {
  // Heavy computing goes here
  for(int i=0; i < 4; ++i)
    (*output)[i] = x * y;
  return;
}   
static void FillThings() {
  for(int x=0; x < 4; ++x)
    for(int y=0; y < 4; ++y)
      Generator(x, y, &STATIC_THING[x]);
}   
FillThings();

int main() {
}
```

Is there a way other than precomputing and hardcoding my sequences into arrays to get the compiler to do the lifting on this?  I feel like there should be a way to at least get this done upon the first #include of the header this will live in, but I have only seen it done with classes.  I can use arrays instead of vectors if it will facilitate computation at compile-time.

**EDITS:**

- Although template metaprogramming was suggested, my actual generator algorithm is far too complex to lend itself to this technique.
- Using a Lookup Table seems to be my only other option that will allow me to avoid runtime computation; I will fall back on this if performance continues to be an issue in the future.

Comment: Why not just use a constructor? Instead of `STATIC_THINK`, use an object that holds the vector. You can make it a singleton if desired.

Comment: I have done that in the pass, classes with data members and initializers in the constructor, of which I create one static instance.  I could go that route but I am more interested in figuring out why I can't accomplish this as above, if for no other reason than to learn something new.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do this:

```
static int FillThings() {
  for(int x=0; x < 4; ++x)
    for(int y=0; y < 4; ++y)
     Generator(x, y, &STATIC_THING[x]);
  return 9087;
}   
static int q = FillThings();
```

Comment: I like this solution, it is clear.  Why can't I just call the function though, and why doesn't the compiler complain when it is called in this way? @Kerrek, I haven't seen that notation before, what is it's main use?

Comment: This gives me unused variable warnings, is there a good way to suppress those?

Comment: You could remove the `static`. You could also use `q` in a harmless way somewhere. Adding a `q=0;` in `FillThings` would probably do it.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't initialize from actual literals via a brace initializer, then you could do something like this:

```
typename std::vector<std::vector<int>> my_vector;

static my_vector make_static_data()
{
    my_vector result;
    // ... populate ...
    return result;
}

static const my_vector static_data = make_static_data();
```

Comment: The only problem that I have with this is that in my real code there will be a very large object returned by value.

Comment: @ethereal: Why is that a problem? Almost surely there'll be RVO, and anyway that's during program startup.

Comment: Point taken re: RVO, but one of my concerns is complete program execution time.  I'd rather not leave the optimization up to the compiler when I can make sure of it with minimal effort!

Comment: To be the devil's advocate, I'd say if performance is your concern, you **should** leave it to the compiler, which probably packs more compilation experience than yourself :-)

Answer (score 0):

Not that easy: std::vector is a dynamic structure. It is not "fillable" ar "compile time". It can be  filled in at startup by initializing a static variable with the return of an invoked function, or lambda, that actually fills-up the vector.

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12145366/924727) can be a way.

But a proper "compile time vecotr" should look like a template whose "index" is an int given as a parameter, like

```
template<unsigned idx>
struct THING
{
    static const int value = .... //put a costant expression here
};
```

to be used as `THING<n>::value`.

The "constant expression" can be a `function(THING<idx-1>::value)`, recursively down to a specialized

```
temnplate<>
struct THING<0U> {};
```

That stops the compiler recursion.

There are, however, some limitations: the expression that defines the `value` static member must be a constexpr (so, only integer types, built-in oerations and no `<cmath>`, and just function declared with constexpr), and the value used as `idx` must be itself a constant (not a variable).

Comment: This looks more complex than it is worth.  Is there a way to compute at compile time with arrays instead of vectors?

Comment: After some digging, I think that what you are suggesting is called "template metaprogramming".  My code is a bit too lengthy and complex to lend itself to this technique.

Comment: Short answer: NO.    Long answer: at compile time there are no variables, just integral constants and types. You can play to generate them in dependency of each other, but not assign to variable at compile time. Initialization is a runtime activity.